# problem with overflow and break-down text

Tags: tailwind-css

I using tailwind-overflow, for horizontal scroll in right side.
Bellow example of my code:

```
  <div className="bg-red-300">
        <div className="bg-red-400">
          <div className="container mx-auto pl-3 pr-3 pt-6 pb-6 flex space-x-2  overflow-x-auto">
            <div className="flex space-x-2">
              <div>Explore:</div>
              <div className="font-bold underline">Shoes</div>
              <div className="font-bold underline">Clothing</div>
              <div className="font-bold underline">Accessories</div>
              <div className="font-bold underline">Premium</div>
              <div className="font-bold underline">Sport</div>
              <div className="font-bold underline">Shop All</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

#1 Why word Shop All was break, when screen is mobile? How fix is it?

- screenshot:
  [image]
- demo: https://superb-pothos-b7b687.netlify.app/tailwind-overflow

#2 How I can hide scroll in tailwind?

Answer (score 5):

**#1** **Whitespace**

In order to disable the breaking of your words, you can simply use [Whitespace](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace).

It looks like the class you might want to use here is `whitespace-nowrap`. You can either apply it to your whole document or simply to a specific div:

```
  <div className="font-bold underline whitespace-nowrap">Shop All</div>
```

**#2** **Hide Scroll-bar**

To hide the scrollbar you can use [Overflow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow).

`overflow-hidden` will hide both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

`overflow-x-hidden` will hide the horizontal scrollbar (which is what you need here).

`overflow-y-hidden` will hide the vertical scrollbar.

In your code it can be implemented this way:

```
 <div className="container mx-auto pl-3 pr-3 pt-6 pb-6 flex space-x-2  overflow-x-auto overflow-hidden">
```

Comment: thank you, I have one question, is it possible to remove/hide the scroll?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15HvizjhwpKmxlhjNGogSynq_VOnhpdf0/view

p.s
when I use

I hidden scroll, but I can scroll to right. I want a hidden scroll, but I want to scroll when my mouse is on the text and scroll right on the touchpad.

Comment: @mxcdh, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to create a dynamic scroll hiding? Show a scrollbar when you're hovering over an element?

Answer (score 0):

**2. Hide scrollbar**

You can hide scrollbar by adding new class to your globals.css file:

```
@layer components {
  .scrollbar-hidden {
    @apply [scrollbar-width:_none];

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      @apply hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

Then simply apply it:

```
<div className="scrollbar-hidden"</div>
```